# How to intercept the Content of UIWebView‘s internet connection

Tags: image, caching, uiwebview, load

1. I want get all the content of a loaded `UIWebView`, especially the images.
2. When `UIWebView` loading a img tag, I want load one image from sandbox instead load through the internet from  img url.
3. I know default there is fcCacheData in the SandBox by `UIWebView`, I want create one cacheData of myself and wholly control it, then I can replace the default one. How to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: First of all, welcome to Stackoverflow! It's a nice place if you want to meet programmers, study and find people to **help you** solve your problems. But it's nice if you show us what you have done already ;)